# Can't Connect MongoDB Atlas from mongosh terminal

Tags: mongodb

please help, i cant connect to mongodb atlas. I already set IP access list to anywhre (0.0.0.0/0) but i'm still cant connect to cluster.

mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.5g5fi.mongodb.net/test" --username

Current Mongosh Log ID: 61afebc020cde1996db*****
Connecting to:      mongodb+srv://cluster0.5g5fi.mongodb.net/test
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.5g5fi.mongodb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Agung - "please help, i cant connect to mongodb atlas. I already set IP access list to anywhre (0.0.0.0/0) but i'm still cant connect to cluster."

If you are using MongoDB Atlas - please make sure your changes are deployed.

Here is some useful reading that might help too.

https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-atlas-login-ip-whitelisting/

Answer (score 0):

It's responding from here (I don't have the username or password but the server is responding)
[image]